# Sorting JSON feed

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, object, feed

I've looked around this site and several others and can't quite find anything that answers my question. I'm given the following JSON variable:

```
var jsonObject = {
    "videos": {
        "name": "Video",
        "placement": "3",
        "items": [{
            "title": "Baby Wolf Video",
            "video": "http://www.youtube.com/embed/fccTIlX6mnc",
            "width": "560",
            "height": "315"
        }]
    },
    "images": {
        "name": "Related Images",
        "placement": "5",
        "items": [{
            "title": "",
            "summary": "Boy that's a beautiful car. I want one \"just like it\".",
            "byline": "Chris Hister",
            "mycapture": "false",
            "width": "1011",
            "height": "768"
        }, {
            "title": "",
            "summary": "Boy what an awesome grab. You had to be there to truly appreciate it.",
            "byline": "Number Nine",
            "mycapture": "false",
            "width": "400",
            "height": "600"
        }, {
            "title": "",
            "summary": "The cutest little baby wolf you'll ever find in the wild. We had a lot more pics, but his mom said this was the only one we could post. Better one than none!",
            "byline": "Baby Wolf",
            "mycapture": "false",
            "width": "1280",
            "height": "1024"
        }, {
            "title": "",
            "summary": "Beautiful bird in the wild. It's always fun to get your feet wet just a little, then fly away.",
            "byline": "Wild Bird",
            "mycapture": "false",
            "width": "1992",
            "height": "1422"
        }, {
            "title": "",
            "summary": "The mysterious soldier/pilot from a distant past. This guys has determination written in his gaze, and goggles on his forehead. In other words, he means business!",
            "byline": "The Soldier",
            "mycapture": "false",
            "width": "1120",
            "height": "1368"
        }, {
            "title": "",
            "summary": "Nothing screams America louder than the historical photo. Most people know this image as 'Raising the Flag on Iwo Jima'.",
            "byline": "American Soldiers",
            "mycapture": "false",
            "width": "250",
            "height": "201"
        }, {
            "title": "",
            "summary": "Everyone's favorite, most feared hero has to be Batman. This guy cannot be defeated, no matter what the punishment. He's been stabbed, shot, blown up, tortured, thrown into a pit, and the list goes on. Yet....somehow...he returns.",
            "byline": "Batman",
            "mycapture": "false",
            "width": "1024",
            "height": "768"
        }, {
            "title": "",
            "summary": "Uh oh! It's that time of year again where the ghosts and ghouls come out to play. Looks like this pumpkin won't be doing much of anything on this Halloween until he pays back the money he owes.",
            "byline": "Irresponsible Pumpkin",
            "mycapture": "false",
            "width": "360",
            "height": "450"
        }, {
            "title": "",
            "summary": "As terrifying as this would be in real life, a photo from afar makes it adorable. I would assume these 2 animals are being filmed from miles away in some jungle somewhere. Whatever the case, this is a magical moment between two of nature's wildest creatures.",
            "byline": "Baby and Momma Lion",
            "mycapture": "false",
            "width": "1024",
            "height": "768"
        }, {
            "title": "",
            "summary": "There comes a time in every little leaguers life where they get tackled. No exceptions here to #23 as he goes down with the entire pile. You can't help but respect that type of commitment from a little leaguer.",
            "byline": "Little Leaguer",
            "mycapture": "false",
            "width": "1053",
            "height": "768"
        }, {
            "title": "",
            "summary": "A local community center tells the neighborhood the story of Thanksgiving through the performing arts. After watching this, you'll truly understand why we should all be thankful.",
            "byline": "Community Center",
            "mycapture": "false",
            "width": "350",
            "height": "235"
        }, {
            "title": "",
            "summary": "If you've ever watched X-Men or any cartoon that showcases The Phoenix, then you understand why she's involved here. The Phoenix is a very unique character. In mythology, she has the ability to die (burst into flames), and come back, reborn anew from her own ashes. Talk about chicken or the egg.",
            "byline": "Phoenix",
            "mycapture": "false",
            "width": "1000",
            "height": "1000"
        }]
    },
    "mugs": {
        "name": "null",
        "placement": "2",
        "items": [{
            "title": "",
            "imagelink": "",
            "summary": "",
            "byline": "",
            "date": "",
            "mycapture": "",
            "width": "",
            "height": ""
        }]
    },
    "related": {
        "name": "Related Content",
        "placement": "4",
        "items": [{
            "type": "story",
            "title": "Ride & Drive: Ford Transit",
        }, {
            "type": "story",
            "title": "Weather Forecast for Tuesday",
        }, {
            "type": "story",
            "title": "Resolution passed to self-report bonds",
        }, {
            "type": "gallery",
            "title": "Christmas in Shohola",
        }, {
            "type": "gallery",
            "title": "Wait Until Dark",
        }, {
            "type": "gallery",
            "title": "Big Buck #4",
        }, {
            "type": "link",
            "title": "Facebook",
        }, {
            "type": "link",
            "title": "Twitter",
        }, {
            "type": "link",
            "title": "Google",
        }, ]
    },
    "facts": {
        "name": "Article Facts",
        "placement": "1",
        "items": [{
            "title": "The truth about dangerous cars",
            "summary": "Pop-up semiotics artisan, Neutra flannel meggings yr seitan pug pork belly messenger bag tofu squid whatever bicycle rights. Letterpress forage distillery, normcore Vice Thundercats ethical drinking vinegar tofu cardigan jean shorts lo-fi typewriter tote bag. Crucifix Thundercats fixie lo-fi freegan. Hoodie lo-fi beard plaid quinoa. Farm-to-table YOLO drinking vinegar raw denim master cleanse, mixtape Banksy Intelligentsia High Life. Blue Bottle slow-carb mustache put a bird on it PBR&B keytar. Schlitz migas iPhone deep v four loko four dollar toast, sriracha brunch aesthetic.Aesthetic keytar mustache PBR&B letterpress, 3 wolf moon XOXO. Umami leggings kale chips four dollar toast. Retro 8-bit Intelligentsia Pinterest, VHS cred DIY disrupt umami irony gastropub keytar. Master cleanse meggings beard, umami seitan sartorial small batch flexitarian flannel church-key. PBR&B YOLO Carles church-key, meditation Schlitz sustainable paleo Echo Park Pitchfork High Life meh four loko Vice. Williamsburg Helvetica DIY High Life. Portland raw denim next level vinyl.Hashtag sustainable retro umami. +1 fap Austin meggings cornhole. Vinyl food truck Etsy, Schlitz cronut craft beer deep v chia. Umami vinyl Godard, kale chips semiotics single-origin coffee ethical hashtag swag lumbersexual direct trade. Plaid banh mi deep v, craft beer listicle street art aesthetic. Hoodie viral chillwave literally health goth. Listicle Tumblr tote bag 90's artisan, meditation plaid lomo....",
            "body": "Pop-up semiotics artisan, Neutra flannel meggings yr seitan pug pork belly messenger bag tofu squid whatever bicycle rights. Letterpress forage distillery, normcore Vice Thundercats ethical drinking vinegar tofu cardigan jean shorts lo-fi typewriter tote bag. Crucifix Thundercats fixie lo-fi freegan. Hoodie lo-fi beard plaid quinoa. Farm-to-table YOLO drinking vinegar raw denim master cleanse, mixtape Banksy Intelligentsia High Life. Blue Bottle slow-carb mustache put a bird on it PBR&B keytar. Schlitz migas iPhone deep v four loko four dollar toast, sriracha brunch aesthetic.Aesthetic keytar mustache PBR&B letterpress, 3 wolf moon XOXO. Umami leggings kale chips four dollar toast. Retro 8-bit Intelligentsia Pinterest, VHS cred DIY disrupt umami irony gastropub keytar. Master cleanse meggings beard, umami seitan sartorial small batch flexitarian flannel church-key. PBR&B YOLO Carles church-key, meditation Schlitz sustainable paleo Echo Park Pitchfork High Life meh four loko Vice. Williamsburg Helvetica DIY High Life. Portland raw denim next level vinyl.Hashtag sustainable retro umami. +1 fap Austin meggings cornhole. Vinyl food truck Etsy, Schlitz cronut craft beer deep v chia. Umami vinyl Godard, kale chips semiotics single-origin coffee ethical hashtag swag lumbersexual direct trade. Plaid banh mi deep v, craft beer listicle street art aesthetic. Hoodie viral chillwave literally health goth. Listicle Tumblr tote bag 90's artisan, meditation plaid lomo.",
            "image": {
                "title": "The truth about dangerous cars",
                "credit": "The Joker",
                "caption": "The driver of this car is a joke",
                "width": "0",
                "height": "0",
                "mycapture": "false"
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

I need to somehow sort this by the 'Placement' values assigned to each individual item. For example, the first item should be in spot #3 because it's placement value is 3. The second item should be in spot #5 because it's placement value is 5. I have tried several things here and I can't seem to get it to actually redraw the feed in the sorted way I need.

I won't have access to the server that draws this feed for at least another 6 months. For now, this is all i have to work with. Please help!!! I've spent about 6 hours on this today alone. Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated!

Chris

Answer (score 4):

Following up on Scott's answer:

```
var output = $.map(jsonObject, function (o) {
    return [o];
}).sort(function (a,b) {
    return a.placement - b.placement;
});
```

Comment: This ought to do it--it will convert the object to an array instead.

Comment: I've added this function to the page, but when I spit out jsonObject, it still displays in the exact same original order

Comment: Actually, I have it now. Needed to assign a variable value to the function

Answer (score 2):

The top level of your variable isn't an array, and thus has no notion of *order*.  The closest you could do is extract those items into an array and sort that, or do that with just the keys.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just to add to it: the point is that the top level is an object, not an array, and you cannot sort the properties of an object in JavaScript.

Comment: I'm currently talking to one of the developers that owns this feed. They ask what I need them to make it 'look like' in order for this to meet our current needs. Can you elaborate a bit on what you mean by 'top level is an object'?? And provide an example of the changes that need to be made in order for this to be 'sortable'?

Comment: @ChrisBlackMajikHister It means that you have `var j = {...}`, not `var j = [...]`.

Comment: He means that `jsonObject` is an object: Notice the `{}` wrappers. That means the properties of `jsonObject` are named object properties. e.g. `jsonObject.videos`. You can't 'order' these properties because they are called by name, not order.

Comment: so if I do j = [ ALL FEED ] then that would work? What are my options at that point? And how does that then allow me to sort by placement?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add objects in array with sorting (by placement). try following code

```
   var keyArr = Object.keys(jsonObject);
var newObjectArr = [];
for(var i=0; i<keyArr.length ;i++){
    jsonObject[keyArr[i]].KeyName = keyArr[i];
    newObjectArr[jsonObject[keyArr[i]].placement] = jsonObject[keyArr[i]];
}
```

U will get sorted array of objects. As your placements starts with 1, you will get undefined at zero index of array.